# How to send email using servers that does not require authentication in java?

Tags: java, windows, email

I want to send an email to me whenever user of my application fills the contact us form and clicks the submit button.

I tried with smtp host as "gmail" but it requires username and password.
But i want to send it without authentication....

Please help me????

Answer (score 0):

Run you own SMTP server on your host, and then you can send email without userid/password

Comment: And another spammer is born.. not a very good one but everyone has to start somewhere :)